# Declaring an array with variable length in C

Tags: c

I know defining an array in C is not possible with variable length, but what about just declaring it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int num = 5;
  int array[num];
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(array));
  return 0;
}
```

Above code compiles and prints `20`. Is it undefined behaviour?

### Edit 1:

If I write

```
  int array[num] = {0};
```

I will get `error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`.

### Edit 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(int *in){
  *in = 6;
}

int main ()
{
  int num = 5;
  change(&num);
  int array[num];
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(array));
  return 0;
}
```

`gcc test.c`.

Above prints `24` which is correct. How does the compiler know the correct size during compile time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns the size in *bytes*.

Comment: Thanks, but how is this working tho? how is the compiler allocating the number of bytes correctly?

Comment: I believe you're wrong on two accounts: 1) an array with variable length in C IS possible, and 2) if what you've done compiles, it's not C. It's C++. I take that back. This shouldn't compile in C++ either. Maybe it's just throwing warnings though that I'm used to making into errros with -Wall -Werror. What's your compilation command?

Comment: Defining a variable length array in C99 and later is possible, although it's an optional feature in C11.

Comment: I have added another example above.

Comment: Yes, it's undefined behavior, because %d is not the correct printf directive to print a value of type `sizeof_t`.

Comment: The error message doesn't say you cannot declare a variable length array, only that you cannot use an array initializer with a VLA

Comment: If the compiler can allocate bytes correctly with only declaration, why can't it initialize it them same way too?

Comment: Please post your compile command.

Comment: I added Edit 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is clean C99 code.  C99 added support for VLAs (variable length arrays).  C11 made the support optional.  Your code compiles cleanly, except that the `printf()` should use `%zu` rather than `%d` to print the value from `sizeof()`.

C11 [§6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4) says:

> ¶2 The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

In your code, the size is evaluated at run-time.  You could have code such as:

```
printf("Enter the array size: ");
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0 || n > 1024)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Did not get a valid size\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int array[n];
```

and then printing the size will still be correct — the size is calculated (evaluated) at run-time.  But that's only for VLAs.

VLAs may not be initialized — the standard is clear about that, too — [§6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) says:

> ¶3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.

You cannot write an initializer for a VLA.  That's a 'constraint'; it is mandatory that the compiler complains about the abuse of the standard.

Comment: How does the compiler know the correct size during compile time to allocate the array? Why can't it do the same when I'm initializing the array? I have added `Edit 2`

Comment: Good thing you also clarified that the value of the size variable could well be unknown at compile time (i.e. user input or non trivial expression). In your code snippet you are reading `n` twice though (cannot edit for some reason). Also for the purposes of this example, I think the code could be simpler

Comment: It doesn't know the correct size at compile time.  For a VLA, it determines the correct size at run-time.

Comment: @kyriakosSt — oops;  removed the superfluous `scanf()`.  Thanks!  (Maybe you couldn't edit because I was editing too.)

Comment: But I still don't get why can't it do the same with `int array[num] = {0};`, whatever it's doing. Why is this a problem? and `int array[num];` isn't?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler one of the masters is here. +1

Comment: The C standard says "thou shalt not".  And while it probably could initialize all elements of the array with zero as you'd like, that isn't the way the standard works.  There is a certain logic to the standard — it isn't as flexible as you'd like.  I'd like it to handle ranges of designated initializers for array initialization: `int array[30] = { [12:24] = 39 };` meaning 0..11 and 25..29 are zeroed.  It doesn't do that — GCC has an extension using `...` to separate the ranges, which has its own set of problems.

Comment: so in this case, array is allocated during run time correct? and for some reason  it doesn't/can't initialize it at the same time?

Comment: @Alex you should abide by the standards if you don't want to incur -- > [Ariane 5](https://itsfoss.com/a-floating-point-error-that-caused-a-damage-worth-half-a-billion). By the way, I learned it from Jonathan Leffler as well some years ago.

Comment: Thank you, so just wanted to confirm this again: array is allocated during run time correct? and for some reason  it doesn't/can't initialize it at the same time?

Comment: @Alex — yes, the array is allocated during run-time, and its size is determined at run-time (even in your code —  and even if you'd used `const int n = 5;` because that's a constant integer, not an integer constant).  And there is a blanket prohibition on initialization for a VLA in §6.7.9¶3 that says "thou shalt not provide an initializer for a VLA".

Comment: Oh I thought using `const` makes them like `integer constants`! Is there an article that says their difference?

Comment: @Alex: In C++, yes (`const` does make them into an integer constant as well as a constant integer).   But this is C and the rules are different — they are different languages.  C++ doesn't officially have VLA support — though GCC (the GNU Compiler Collection) does provide support for them via `g++` as an extension, with no initialization, of course.